# Modelstate invalid due to foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Creating of object fails due to the fact that the ModelState is invalid. Any help will be appreciated. The simplified model looks like:

```
public partial class Timerecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int locationID { get; set; }
    public int teamID { get; set; }
    public int actionID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime currentTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }
}
```

The creating of a correctly supplied Timerecord fails due to an error:
"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Project.Models.Action' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

All attributes of the Timerecord are fine, but both Action and Location are Null (which is not a problem... as the foreign keys are correct). Do I have to set de foreign objects myself and then reevaluate the model, or I have to supply a constructor Action(string)?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Timerecord tm)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Timings.Add(tm);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));
                ...
            }
            ...
```

The problem seems to be caused by the Create method of the Controller (simplified):

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Timerecord tm = new Timerecord();
        LocationDBContext dbLoc = new LocationDBContext();
        ActionDBContext dbAct = new ActionDBContext();

        tm.currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        tm.locationID = 1;
        tm.actionID = 5;
        tm.Location = dbLoc.Location.Find(tm.locationID);
        /* THE PROBLEM: tm.Action = dbAct.Action.Find(tm.actionID); PROBLEM HERE */

        ViewData.Model = tm;
        return View();
    }
```

Location causes no problem, Action does..
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: The error occurs "during" the create of the record: public ActionResult Create(Timerecord tr)
The ModelState is invalid within this method.

Comment: Can you please add this code to the question?

Comment: Is added now - see description

Comment: After adding @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Action, null) in the Create.cshtml the state is valid... not a satisfying solution... but it works.

Comment: Sorry @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Action, null) was not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renamed Action to Activity and everything works fine!
Guess the binding (...) messed up with System.Action?!? Got no other explaination. Perhaps someone can confirm this kind of troubles.